# Query do not insert

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have a code on a page(insertrespondent2.php) that should insert some values from a form that is on another site(registerrespondent2.php). After it has inserted the values in the database, it a text should be showed that confirms that the values are inserted. The problem is that I do get the confirmation-text, but no values are inserted.

**registerrespondent2.php**

```
<?php
    $quest = "SELECT coalesce(max(rid)+1,1) AS id FROM temp_members_db";
    $result = $mysqli->query($quest);

   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {   
   ?>                              
<form action='insertrespondent2.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' name='insertrespondent' onsubmit='return validateForm()'>
    <input type='hidden' name='ridsend' value='". $row["id"] ."'>
    <b>Company E-mail:</b><br> <input type='text' size='35' name='minemail'/><br>
    <b>Subject: </b><br><input type='text' size='35' name='subject'/><br>
    <b>First name: </b><br><input type='text' size='35' name='firstname' id='firstname'><br>
    <b>Last name: </b><br><input type='text' size='35' name='lastname' id='lastname'><br>
    <b>Respondent E-mail: </b><br><input type='text' size='35' name='email' id='email'><br><br>
    <b>Message: </b><br><textarea rows='10' cols='30' name='message'></textarea> <br>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Skicka test'>
</form>
<?php  
     }
         } 
 ?>
```

**insertrespondent2.php**

```
$confirm_code=md5(uniqid(rand()));
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname =  $_POST['lastname'];
$email =     $_POST['email'];
$from =      $_POST['minemail'];
$subject =   $_POST['subject'];
$message =   $_POST['message'];
$ridret = $_POST['ridsend'];

$sql= "INSERT INTO temp_members_db(firstname,lastname,confirm_code, email, pid, rid) VALUES('$firstname','$lastname','$confirm_code', '$email', '" . $_SESSION['pid2'] . "','$ridret')";
$b = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.'; 
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo; } 
else { 
    echo "<h1>Test is sended</h1><br>";
    echo "<br><a href='dashboardcompany2.php'><button id='projectbutton'>Dashboard</button></a>
    <a href='registerrespondent2.php'><button id='projectbutton'>Add new</button></a>"; }
```

[image]

Comment: SQL_Injection is strong with this one... Please use prepared statements...

Comment: @Naruto prepared statements alone do not protect from this. The trick is to use parameter binding with prepared statements.

Comment: @Max you are checking `$mail->send()`. Check `$b` whether its true or false .

Comment: There is no error checking or handling at all implemented for the query. So how do you expect to detect an issue then? Apart from that: take a look into your error log file, I'd say.

Comment: @arkascha have you ever used prepared statements without binding parameters?!

Comment: @arkascha I do have this on the beginning of my php "ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);"

Comment: @arkascha The thing is that it has worked perfect for months until today for some reason...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: and no way of knowing if the session was started along with "if" this is JS related, seeing you're using some here `onsubmit='return validateForm()'`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I get this message, even though my "pid" column isn't AUTO-INCREMENT:
Errormessage: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'pid' at row 1

Comment: @arkascha I get this message, even though my "pid" column isn't AUTO-INCREMENT: Errormessage: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'pid' at row 1

Comment: @Naruto Certainly I have. In certain cases where no critical parameter is involved this can make sense. But that is not the point. you have to consider that you give an advice here to an probably less experienced user. Telling him "use prepared statements" only suggests that this would protect from sql injection, which simply is _not_ the case, sorry.

Comment: could be the placement of `rid` in your query, and/or the column's type.

Comment: You should generally prefer the error log file over displaying errors in your output.

Comment: @arkascha I don't get it how to how to use the error log... Looked at this: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)

Comment: The error log file is one of the log files your http server writes (if you use php as a module within the http server which is the case in >99% of all php usages). You don't need a special function for that. It only has to advantage over displaying errors that you get _all_ errors raised by php in chronological order and that your display is not broken by all the notices, warnings and errors. The files location is configured in your http server configuration, default is something like `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. Use `tail -f <logfile>` to monitor it in background.

Comment: @arkascha Is it ok with you if I ask you to please edit my code in the question so I can see where I should add that?

Comment: Once more: you do not need any special function, there is nothing that has to be modified in your code. This is a general thing configured just like your `display_errors=on`, your http server certainly already writes that log file. The only difference is that you don't display errors somewhere strewn chaotically into your output where you _might_ be able to spot them, but that you look at the server side error log file instead. That is more precise and readable. Not more, not less.

Comment: @arkascha But how do I get to the errors then? Where do I find them?

Comment: @arkascha Check the picture of my columns to see if its something wrong there, since I recently got the error " Errormessage: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'pid' at row 1

Comment: @Fred-ii- Check the picture of my columns in my question to see if its something wrong there, since I recently got the error " Errormessage: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'pid' at row 1

Comment: @Max It seems that this `coalesce(max(rid)+1,1)` might be the other way around `max(coalesce(rid)+1,1)` from what I found while Googling. Try that and see, but not 100% sure as it seems that it could be used both ways. Also, make sure that both `rid` and `pid` column lengths aren't too short. Try increasing its lengths. Also do a `var_dump()` and view your HTML source to see what `<input type='hidden' name='ridsend' value='". $row["id"] ."'>` reveals. Check if there's any whitespace being introduced somewhere.

Comment: @Max and `$ridret = $_POST['ridsend'];` since you're fetching from db from the hidden input, try making that as a GET `$ridret = $_GET['ridsend'];` or placing `(int)` before it `$ridret = (int)$_GET['ridsend'];`

Comment: @Max Also, looking at your table structure and your query, `(firstname,lastname,confirm_code, email, pid, rid)` 
is probably because of the order you gave it. So try 
`(rid, pid, firstname, lastname, confirm_code, email)` - Try that and my other comments and ping me if anything gives. ;-)

Comment: Can we see the connection?